# How can I connect to database with app user?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, ubuntu

I'm trying to write a todo app in NodeJS a la [this link](http://mherman.org/blog/2015/02/12/postgresql-and-nodejs/). Making the switch from M$ to NodeJS.

I want to have a separate user account, so I

`sudo useradd pg_todo_app_user` and
`sudo passwd pg_todo_app_user`.

The bash gods smile.

Then, wanting to communicate to the postgresql server that I've got a user coming through, I try the following:

```
$ su - postgres
Password: 
$ psql todo
psql (9.4.4)
Type "help" for help.

todo=# CREATE USER pg_todo_app_user WITH PASSWORD 'password!'
todo-# GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE todo to pg_todo_app_user
todo-# \q
$ exit
```

So far, everyone is happy. Except when I try this:

```
$ node database.js 
events.js:85
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
        ^
error: password authentication failed for user "pg_todo_app_user"
```

Here is my connection string:

`var connectionString = process.env.DATABASE_URL || 'postgresql://pg_todo_app_user:password!@localhost:5432/todo';`

I checked the following and the output is not promising:

```
todo=# -c \du
                             List of roles
 Role name |                   Attributes                   | Member of 
-----------+------------------------------------------------+-----------
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication+| {}
           | Password valid until infinity                  |
```

...that's it. What am I missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

If you are running nodeJS and PostgreSQL server on the same host then the solution could be to change your pg_hba.conf file to this:

```
host    todo             pg_todo_app_user             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    todo             pg_todo_app_user             ::1/128                 md5
```

Then restart postgres server and try again.

Comment: Wanted to mark this as answer, because it seems like it fits the documentation, but unfortunately, I tried it in this case and it didn't work. `CREATE ROLE` seems to be the proper command on the db.